# How to prevent jQuery DataTable tools to be redrawn after reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable, datatables

I use jQuery DataTable and there are some tools i.e. Filter, Checkbox, etc. on a jQuery DataTable and after calling every **table.ajax.reload()** all of them are rendered on the callback of AJAX request and this causing the checkbox values cannot be keep. So, is there any way to prevent the toolbar of the DataTable to be redrawn on every reload? On the other hand, what is the best approach (i.e. using a hidden value or cookie) to retain checkbox values after reload?

```
<input type="hidden" id="key" name="Key" />

$(document).ready(function () {

//code omitted for brevity
"fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
    aoData.push({ "name": "all", "value": $('#key').val() });                   
    $.getJSON(sSource, aoData, function (json) {
        fnCallback(json);
        $("div.toolbar").html('<input type="checkbox" name="GetAll" 
            id="isGetAll" value="$('#key').val()"/> Get all records');
    });
},
//...



    $(document).on('change', '#isGetAll', function () {

        if ($("#key").val()) {
            $("#key").val('TRUE');
        } else {
            $("#key").val('FALSE');
        }
        table.ajax.reload();
    });
});
```

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira Any idea regarding to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try with State saving property of data tables.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        stateSave: true
    } );
} );
```

[Reference 1](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html)

[Reference 2](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave)

[This thread may help You.](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/30116/savestate-and-page-reloads-with-ajax)

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I was out of office. I have tried ann of the methods using **stateSave** but for every state, the checkbox's selected state lost. I deleted all the unnecessary part of the code for testing this and I just leave **table.ajax.reload();** in the checkbox's change event and leave **$("div.toolbar").html('<input type="checkbox" name="GetAll" id="isGetAll" value="$('#key').val()"/> Get all records');** in callback method. In addition to this, I also tried to use this line after **$('#example').DataTable( {} );** block, but for this time checkbox is not rendered.

Comment: Any reply regarding to this problem please?

Comment: Do you have any knowledge about **jquery.cookie**? Could you please have a look at [Cannot retain checkbox value using jquery.cookie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39889632/cannot-retain-checkbox-value-using-jquery-cookie)? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Any ide about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40571553/jquery-datatable-individual-column-searching-on-table-header) question?